CoreData async perform method usage
I faced some UI Hangs when using viewContext. So I used async perform method on viewContext to avoid blocking UI.
But I'm still getting UI Hang reports. Here is my code and main thread stack.
func fetchedResultController(sectionNameKeyPath: String? = nil,
                             cacheName: String? = nil,
                             fetchList: Bool = true) async -> NSFetchedResultsController<T> {

    if self.request.sortDescriptors == nil {
       self.request.sortDescriptors = []
    }
    
    if !fetchList {
        self.request.fetchLimit = 1
    }

    let fetchedResultController =  NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: self.request,
                                                              managedObjectContext: self.context,
                                                              sectionNameKeyPath: sectionNameKeyPath,
                                                              cacheName: cacheName)

    await self.context.perform {
        do {
            try fetchedResultController.performFetch()
        } catch let error  {
            // ...
        }
    }

    return fetchedResultController
}

Thread 0 - com.apple.main-thread - (TH_STATE_WAITING)
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib +0x1560 _kevent_id
1  libdispatch.dylib +0x267d0     __dispatch_kq_poll
2  libdispatch.dylib +0x271b8     __dispatch_event_loop_wait_for_ownership
3  libdispatch.dylib +0x13590     ___DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__
4  libdispatch.dylib +0x13158     __dispatch_sync_f_slow
5  CoreData +0x9d120              -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]
6  CoreData +0x9c5fc              -[NSFetchedResultsController _recursivePerformBlockAndWait:withContext:]
7  CoreData +0x270d8              _developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform
8  CoreData +0x9d0e8              -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]
9  CoreData +0x9c5fc              -[NSFetchedResultsController _recursivePerformBlockAndWait:withContext:]
10 CoreData +0x9c208              -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]
11 MailLib +0x3a094               specialized closure #1 in Fetcher.fetchedResultController(sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:fetchList:)
12 MailLib +0x3e2d8               partial apply for specialized closure #1 in Fetcher.fetchedResultController(sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:fetchList:) (<compiler-generated>)
13 CoreData +0xd0320              closure #1 in closure #1 in NSManagedObjectContext._rethrowsHelper_perform_enqueued<A>(_:rescue:)
14 CoreData +0xd0180              thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> ()
15 CoreData +0x270d8              _developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform
16 libdispatch.dylib +0x3dd0      __dispatch_client_callout
17 libdispatch.dylib +0x125a0     __dispatch_main_queue_drain
18 libdispatch.dylib +0x121b4     __dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
19 CoreFoundation +0x5670c        ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
20 CoreFoundation +0x53910        ___CFRunLoopRun
21 CoreFoundation +0x52cd4        _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
22 GraphicsServices +0x11a4       _GSEventRunModal
23 UIKitCore +0x40a908            <redacted>
24 UIKitCore +0x4be9cc            UIApplicationMain
25 Works +0xee7b18                main (AppDelegate.swift:13:7)
26 dyld +0x3ce48                  start

My assumption is that calling performFetch in perform block of viewContext makes a recursive call and dead lock.
Do I have to use async perform on only bg context?
And using bg context for NSFetchedResultsController could be a solution?
We're using it for UI though.
Edit
The request used by NSFetchedResultsController looks like this.
<NSFetchRequest: 0x6000028c8c40> (entity: Mail; predicate: ((NOT folderSN IN {4, 5, 2}) AND (subject CONTAINS[cd] "testdd" OR ((preview CONTAINS[cd] "testdd" OR htmlBody CONTAINS[cd] "testdd") OR bodyKeywords CONTAINS[cd] "testdd") OR from CONTAINS[cd] "testdd" OR (toKeywords CONTAINS[cd] "testdd" OR toList CONTAINS[cd] "testdd") OR ccList CONTAINS[cd] "testdd") AND (NOT sendingStatus IN {3, 2, 4, 1}) AND (listId & 2 == 2 OR sendingStatus > 0)); sortDescriptors: ((
    "(sendingStatus, descending, NO, compare:)",
    "(searchServerOrder, descending, NO, compare:)",
    "(firstLocatedTime, descending, NO, compare:)",
    "(mailSN, descending, NO, compare:)"
)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )

And I used NSFetchedResultsController's fetchedObjects in a tableView's cellForRowAt method.

FRC fetches must be executed with the view context. You arent showing your fetch request so it is hard to tell what is causing the hang.

@MartinM Thanks for the reply! I added the request and how to use it. By the way, How can I know that frc must use view context? is there any reference?
